# Why are nextElementSibling and nextSibling null when sibling exists?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In this HTML structure:

```
<table id="outside">
  <tr>
    <td id="t1">one</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="t2">two</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Why does the following script:

```
// Function to change the content of t2
function modifyText() {
  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  console.dir(t2.firstChild.nextElementSibling);
  console.dir(t2.firstChild.nextSibling);
  if (t2.firstChild.nodeValue == "three") {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";
  } else {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "three";
  }
}

// add event listener to table
var el = document.getElementById("outside");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

why do `nextElementSibling` and `nextSibling` have null values. I would expect them to be the sibling `td` tags.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qesifiti/1/edit)

Comment: I don't see any references to `nextElementSibling` or `nextSibling` in your code.

Comment: @BoltClock You can see them in the console where `t2.firstChild` is printed.

Comment: Oh OK. So we're looking at those properties for `t2.firstChild`.

Comment: you´re consoling the firstchild, and that doesn´t have siblings, the "td" does, but not the text node inside td

Comment: @SebastianUrielMurawczik so obvious now. Thanks much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`t2` refers to `td#t2`, since the element with the ID "t2" is the `td` element itself.

`t2.firstChild`, therefore, refers to the text node inside `t2`, which is its only child. An only child does not have any siblings.

You probably meant to look at `t2` itself instead:

```
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
console.log(t2.nextElementSibling);
console.log(t2.nextSibling);
```